# Where my images are saved with this provider

Tags: android

As per [this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Accessing-the-Camera-and-Stored-Media#setup-fileprovider), I defined my file provider as:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
<!-- See table below.  The external-files-path DOES NOT require external storage permissions. -->
<external-files-path
    name="images"
    path="Pictures" />

<!-- share the entire application specific directory -->
<external-path name="all_dirs" path="."/>
</paths>
```

And saved the image as:

```kotlin
   @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun createImageFile(): Uri { 
        val storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        val file = File(
            getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png"
        )
        // wrap File object into a content provider. NOTE: authority here should match authority in manifest declaration
        var image = FileProvider.getUriForFile(ctx, "com.example.provider", file)

        return image
    }
```

When I took a photo in my app, I found the path to be:

```sh
content://com.example.provider/images/share_image_1628967567663.png
```

I searched the file at gallery but could not see it, where can I find it?

Comment: If you mean that you used a gallery app and looked for the image, it will not appear there, particularly on Android 10+ devices. First, most gallery apps will use the `MediaStore`, and files written to the filesystem are not added automatically to the `MediaStore`. You would need to take steps to do that yourself. Second, on Android 10+, the `MediaStore` will not index files that are in app-specific storage.

Comment: mmm, thanks @CommonsWare, so how to do it, I want to see them, do I need to change something in my provider?

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried to look then in both gallery and File apps, but could not see any :(

Comment: @CommonsWare how can I save the photos in a folder like the ones used in messengers, whatsapp, telegram and so on, it can be seen in file explorer?

Comment: For Android 9 and below, you can use `MediaScannerConnection` to trigger `MediaStore` to index some file. On Android 10 and up, you need to write your images to a public location, [probably using `MediaStore` itself](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/12/21/scoped-storage-stories-storing-mediastore.html).